# C# query List<Tuple> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and I need to start reading when item1 is great than myVariable.
I can do it using a loop and an if statement but can someone help me to do it using LINQ?

```
var listDate = new List<Tuple<DateTime, double>>();

foreach (var item in listDate)
{
    if (item.Item1 > myVariable)
         Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @GrantWinney in my case the list is sorted, I just need to start reading from some point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LINQ counterpart of `if` is [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime, double>> query = listDate.Where(t => t.Item1 > myVariable);
```

You can use a `foreach`-loop or another method like `ToList` to *consume* the query.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to `Where`:

```
var result = listData.SkipWhile(t => t.Item1 <= myVariable);
```

*Note*: This assumes that collection is ordered with respect to `Item1`. And then "skip" may be more clear as it is closer to the intent "I need to start reading when item1 is great than myVariable" than standard collection filtering with `Where`.

Comment: These are not functionally the same. Your method assumes the tuples are ordered by date.

Comment: I see SkipWhile for the first time. Is this sometimes better than Where? It looks like just Where with negated statement.

Comment: Although, to be fair, the question does suggest that the items may be ordered ("I need to start reading when item1 is great than myVariable"). It's not clear.

Comment: @dcastro, true but from "start reading" OP's clause I believe they are ordered.

Comment: @PawełReszka, in this case (ordered collection) it is just (IMHO) better way of describing intention of the code. But it is not "better" in general in any way.